# ethereumjs-wallet/hdkey is no more in npm

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, ethereumjs

how to generate multiple addresses from single mnemonic?

```
var hdkey = require("ethereumjs-wallet/hdkey")
var bip39 = require("bip39");

// You can generate a mnemonic seed with bip39 library
var mnemonic = "seed sock milk ";
var path = "m/44'/60'/0'/0/0";

var hdwallet = hdkey.fromMasterSeed(bip39.mnemonicToSeed(mnemonic));
var wallet = hdwallet.derivePath(path).getWallet();
var address = "0x" + wallet.getAddress().toString("hex");
console.log(address)
```

Comment: have you been able to find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question but since no answer: the last number of the derivation path is to be changed to generate a new address: 0 is the first address, that you get with path `m/44'/60'/0'/0/0`, then use `m/44'/60'/0'/0/1`, then `m/44'/60'/0'/0/2` ...

Answer (score 0):

You can also use ethers.js for this. See: https://docs.ethers.io/ethers.js/html/api-wallet.html#wallet